# Presetting values on a foreign entity relationship in a ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using ModelForm to generate some forms. 
One of my forms has a ManyToOne relationship. This forms corresponds to the "One" side of the relationship and I know (and have) the value of the ID I need that value to be.

The form generates a select box with all the possible values that exist in the database but I don't want the user to chose.

How can I:
- Fix that value on that specific field without depending on interface? (I can do it via JQuery but it's not an elegant way)
- Preventing that select box from being shown?

Here is the code for the ModelForm:

```
class SomeModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

And to generate the forms:

```
def some_model_signup(request, fk_id):
    SomeModelSet = modelformset_factory(SomeModel)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = SomeModelSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # do something.
    else:
        formset = SomeModelFormSet(queryset=SomeModel.objects.none())
    return render_to_response("form.html", {
        "formset": formset, "fk_id": fk_id,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Is it on `One` side or at `Many` side form?

Comment: Why do you use a formset when you don't want the user to choose?

Comment: @Rohan: This signup form corresponds to the one side, which is why I pass the fk_id of the many side.

Comment: @djangophilipp: I want him to chose the other values just not that one. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: when you say " I know (and have) the value of the ID I need " - what do you mean? where do you have it, and how?

Answer (score 0):

There's a `queryset` parameter you can pass to the `SomeModelSet` as explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset).