# Hiding foreign key fields from ModelForms in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using django ModelForms to generate my input forms.

I specify in my form model to only use a set of fields:

```
class <Model>Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = <Model>
        fields = ('date', 'comment_1')
```

My model is defined as:

```
class <Model>(models.Model):
    fk_id_1 = models.ForeignKey(<ExternalModel1>, null=False, blank=False)
    fk_id_2  = models.ForeignKey(<ExternalModel2>, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    comment_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

However, the ForeignKey boxes show.

How is it possible for me to hide them from the form? Also, how can I set the values for those dropboxes from within the view and not sure, say JQuery externally to do it? Ideally, after the ''is_valid()'' check, I would like to set the IDs of my Foreign Keys and then do save. Maybe I should look into solving this using another way?

This is the View:

```
def <Model>_add(request, trainee_id):

    <Model>FormSet = modelformset_factory(<Model>)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = <Model>FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid() and formset.has_changed():
            formset.save()
            # do something.
    else:
        formset = <Model>FormSet(queryset=<Model>.objects.none())
    return render_to_response("<Model>_add.html", {
        "formset": formset, "fk_id_1": fk_id_1,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I can solve this issue using JQuery but I would like a more elegant approach.

Note: I tried posting this earlier but I think it was not as clear as it is here: [Presetting values on a foreign entity relationship in a ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752592/presetting-values-on-a-foreign-entity-relationship-in-a-modelform) ... I didn't understand exactly what was said about QuerySet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be a bit more explicit in how you define the form:

```
class <Model>Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = <Model>
        fields = ['date', 'comment_1']
        exclude = ['fk_id_1', 'fk_id_2']
```

Then in your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def <Model>_add(request, trainee_id):

    <Model>FormSet = modelformset_factory(<Model>)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = <Model>FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid() and formset.has_changed():
            forms = formset.save(commit=False)
            for form in forms:
               form.fk_id_1 = SomeOtherModel.objects.get(pk=1)
               form.fk_id_2 = SomeOtherModel.objects.get(pk=2)
               form.save()
            # add your success redirect here, for example:
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        formset = <Model>FormSet(queryset=<Model>.objects.none())
    return render(request, "<Model>_add.html", {"formset": formset})
```

Answer (score 1):

Every ModelForm also has a save() method. [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

or:

in views.py

```
form.instance.fk_id_1 = ...
form.instance.fk_id_2 = ...
form.save()
```

Comment: And what about the fields showing up when I specify them not to do so?

Comment: if you only want to display `fk_id_1`, by context to tempalte.